# evaluating 'this.props = props' React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Estou aprendendo react native e estou com uma dificuldade. Estou seguindo esse tutorial: https://blog.logrocket.com/navigating-react-native-apps-using-react-navigation/

Realizo todo procedimento igual, mas não funciona. Eu recebo esse erro toda vez que executo meu app

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha HomeScreen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';


export default class HomeScreen extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text> Home Screen </Text>
            <Button
              title="Sobre"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('About')}
            />
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Meu App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './components/HomeScreen';
import AboutScreen from './components/AboutScreen';

export default class App extends Component() {
  render(){
    return <AppContainer/>
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  About: {
    screen: AboutScreen
  }
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Versões que estou utilizando:

```
"expo": "^33.0.0",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
"react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
```

Estou utilizando expo para emular meu app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sua própria mensagem de erro aponta a linha 8 voce tem: `export default class App extends Component()`, troque para `export default class App extends React.Component`

se não funcionar, verifique se a prop navigation esta chegando no componente com componentDidMount()

Comment: Não era totalmente isso, mas minha classe eu estava chamando de Component() {, correto é apenas Component {